# Feedme Fails - logs not helpful

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm trying to import an ExpressionEngine blog into Craft. I've set up an xml feed on the EE site and limited it to two entries for testing purposes. Once it's working will import everything.

The issue I"m having is that when I run the import it fails and the feed me logs aren't helpful.

```
EE Blog: Finished database backup
EE Blog: Starting database backup
```

That's all I get.

I've done field mapping and set a unique identify for existing elements (there should be none at this point).

Sent a support email to feedme via the CP two days ago but haven't gotten a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure your **Primary Element** field in the initial setup is the entry element and not the top level in your xml file, for example:

```
<root>
 <article></article>
 <article></article>
</root>
```

`article` should be the **Primary Element**